# Cannot disable enter key on a textarea

Tags: javascript, forms, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

hi guys
i am trying to disable enter key from submitting the form in a textarea

using the following function:

```
function noenter() {
    return !(window.event && window.event.keyCode == 13); 
    }
```

html code:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="myObject" method="post" action="${myUrl}">
 <form:textarea path="name" class="new_obj submits_on_return" cols="40" rows="3"  onkeypress="return noenter()"></form:textarea>
```

but it doesn't work at all, it always submits, any ideas why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function disableEnterKey(e)
{
     var key;
     if(window.event)
          key = window.event.keyCode;     //IE
     else
          key = e.which;     //firefox
     if(key == 13)
          return false;
     else
          return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: could you please mention the answer to be correct by clicking the small tickmark on the left?

Comment: you need to modify the textarea tag as `<form:textarea path="name" class="new_obj submits_on_return" cols="40" rows="3"  onkeypress="return noenter(event)"></form:textarea>` then it will work. I didnt notice this error.

Comment: but my function noenter doesn't take parameters ?

Comment: other idea, is how to make the enter button make the same action as clicking the button with mouse ?